# How can I fix an image not displaying?

Tags: reactjs

Hello guys I downloaded a template and I'm using its the home page to create a website using reactJs,
I created a class component then I transformed the code from HTML to JSX.
The home page contains a slider with 3 images I created a slider but the images are not showing can you please help meto fix this?
this is the code

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import '../assets/styles/style.css';
import '../assets/styles/style-rtl.css';
import Slider from "react-slick";
import img1 from "../assets/images/image_header_04.jpg";
import img2 from "../assets/images/image_header_03.jpg";
import img3 from "../assets/images/image_news_05.jpg"
class Home extends Component
{
    render()
    {
        const settings = {
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 500,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true
          };

        return(
<main className="main">
        {/* Slider */}
        
        <section className="intro-slider ltr section-rounding">
          
          <div className="intro-slider__image swiper-container overlay">
            <div className="swiper-wrapper">
            <Slider {...settings}>
              {/* Image 1 */}
              <div className="swiper-slide">
                <div className="coverSlider js-parallax js-image" data-image={img1} />
              </div>
              {/* Image 2 */}
              <div className="swiper-slide">
                <div className="coverSlider js-parallax js-image" data-image={img2} />
              </div>
              {/* Image 3 */}
              <div className="swiper-slide">
                <div className="coverSlider js-parallax js-image" data-image={img3} />
              </div>
              </Slider>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </section>
        
        {/* /Slider */}
        
      </main>
);
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the images correctly on React, you need to replace the div tags you have for an  tag.

Replace this:

```
<div className="swiper-slide">
                <div className="coverSlider js-parallax js-image" data-image={img1} />
              </div>
```

For this;

```
<img src={img1} alt="image description" />
```

Comment: Yes I replaced it by this but always the same problem

Comment: What is been displayed on the browser console?